# How to read windows registry data on remote machine using java

Tags: java, registry, jna

I am trying to read some user-defined windows registry data on remote machine using java.
I am able to read my local machine registry data using jna and even update it   back.
Can anybody help on how to read/write data to remote machine using java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WinAPI has a function named [`RegConnectRegistry`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724840.aspx) which may be what you're looking for:

> Establishes a connection to a predefined registry key on another computer

```cpp
LONG WINAPI RegConnectRegistry(
    _In_opt_ LPCTSTR lpMachineName,
    _In_     HKEY    hKey,
    _Out_    PHKEY   phkResult
);
```

In **Java**, the function may look like the following, granted that you've added the [`jna-platform`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.dev.jna/jna-platform) library as a dependency which provides ready-made API types and functions:

```java
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinReg.HKEY;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinReg.HKEYByReference;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinReg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
import com.sun.jna.win32.W32APIOptions;

interface MyAdvapi32 extends StdCallLibrary {
    MyAdvapi32 INSTANCE = (MyAdvapi32) Native.loadLibrary(
        "advapi32",
        MyAdvapi32.class,
        W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS
    );

    int RegConnectRegistry(String machineName, HKEY hKey, HKEYByReference result);
    int RegCloseKey(HKEY key);
}
```

You might notice the `W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS` used in the library load. The Windows API provides two different implementations for functions which use strings: one for Unicode strings and one for ANSI strings. While the function is named `RegConnectRegistry`, the implementations which JNA finds in the DLL are named `RegConnectRegistryW` (Unicode) and `RegConnectRegistryA` (ANSI). However, these probably are not your concern since you're not writing native code.

Passing the default options in lets JNA use the correct function names, avoiding a confusing-at-best `UnsatisfiedLinkError`.

**Usage** might look like this:

```
HKEYByReference result = new HKEYByReference();
int returnCode = MyAdvapi32.INSTANCE.RegConnectRegistry(
    "\\\\server-name",
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
    result
);

if (returnCode != 0) {
    throw new Win32Exception(returnCode);
}

HKEY key = result.getValue();

// ... use the key, then once done with it ...

MyAdvapi32.INSTANCE.RegCloseKey(key);
```

By the way, `jna-platform` library [does provide mappings](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Advapi32.java) for the `Advapi32` library, but `RegConnectRegistry` seems to be missing. Ideally, you'd probably create a pull request and add it in, but YMMV as to how quickly they roll out a new release with the addition.

EDIT: I've created a [pull request](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/pull/935) to JNA to get this function added in.

Comment: hi cubrr, thanks for update. I tired as you suggested and getting java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'RegConnectRegistry': The specified procedure could not be found.

Comment: @Rao I've edited my answer's Java example and added an explanation for the error below it. Let me know if it works!

Comment: thanks cubrr, it worked. need some more info on user access. how to check if user has access or not before accessing the registry and only if user has access. FYI, all keys are user-defined only not system created/application related.

Comment: @Rakesh Maybe [`RegGetSecurity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379313.aspx)?